# Is there a grammatical categorisation for 'so to speak' and 'as it were'?

Tags: phrases, adjuncts

When speaking and writing, we often use phrases such as 'so to speak', 'as it were', 'if you will', 'to say the least', and 'to name a few'. I understand how to use these; however, I can't identify their place in linguistics. An easy classification would be an aside or adjunct, but I was wondering if there is a more specific category for these phrases?

Comment: Yes, adjuncts: more specifically supplementary adjuncts. Supplements are loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Comment: Very useful information, Bill. Thanks for your continued help with my queries. I will wait to see if anyone else has a different response, but if you would like to write that as an answer, I will accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *so to speak, as it were, if you will, to say the least, to
> name a few*

Yes: these are adjuncts or, more specifically, supplementary adjuncts.

Supplements are loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Here's an example:

> *The senior Nazis Borman, Goering and Hess,* [*to name a few*], *were all accused of*
> *crimes against humanity*.

In that example, the bracketed element "to name a few" is a supplementary adjunct. The element that the supplement refers to (called the 'anchor') is the noun phrase "the senior Nazis Borman, Goering and Hess".